Cannot Connect Mysql DB to Google Looker Studio
I'm trying to connect my MySQL DB to Google Looker Studio, but I'm getting an Error-Message:
enter image description here
Translation: Could not connect because server reported an error.
The Setting I'm using:
MySQL 8.0.36
Hostet on Exoscale Servers
IPV4s from Google are white-listed via CIDR, according to this support document
https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7088031#zippy=%2Cthemen-in-diesem-artikel%2Cliste-der-ip-adressen-anzeigen
SLL: not activated
Does any of you has an idea what to do?
Thank you,
Christian

looked in google support - did not find any help
did try jdbc url also - same error

Expectation: I'm stuck in the 1st Step after authorize. I would expect that I see the tables the user has access to.

To resolve the connection issue with Google Looker Studio, you need to enable SSL.
You can do this by activating SSL and uploading the server certificate, which you can download from the Exoscale portal.
The certificate is located in the CA certificate section of your Mysql DBaaS.
Once SSL is enabled and the certificate is uploaded, authentication should work as expected. This approach worked for me and should resolve your connection error.
Best regards,

Shayma -


Hi Shayma,
thank you for the hint. This did the job!
Best regards, Christian
